# Turpentine/Varnish does not flush on expected events

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, turpentine

I run an Varnish(version 3.0.5)->Magento(1.9.2.1)/Turpentine(0.6.9) server and have difficulties figuring out the correct configuration for the ESI blocks of my theme (bookshop form ubertheme https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-themes/bookshop/) shopping cart.

I think I do understand now more or less how the whole thing is supposed to work, but somehow I seem to miss some major points still. This is what I did so far:

- I let turpentine create a configuration for varnish and I copied it into the varnish machine. (I can't use the turpentine functionality of pushing the config directly, since this is not allowed by my hosting environment)
- I added the an ESI configuration to my theme's local.xml to make the jmtoolbar private (see config below). In my trial-and-error attempts I included pretty much every possible event in the flush_event section. Probably this is not needed, but in my case it does not seem to work at all.

my theme's local.xml:

```
<reference name="jmtoolbar">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <method>ajax</method>
                <access>private</access>
                <ttl>60</ttl>
                <scope>global</scope>
                <flush_events>
                    <checkout_cart_save_after/>
                    <sales_quote_save_after/>
                    <sales_quote_delete_after/>
                    <catalog_product_compare_add_product/>
                    <catalog_product_compare_remove_product/>
                    <catalog_product_compare_item_collection_clear/>
                    <wishlist_item_save_after/>
                    <wishlist_item_delete_after/>
                    <checkout_cart_product_add_after/>
                    <checkout_cart_update_items_after/>
                    <checkout_cart_product_update_after/>
                </flush_events>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

Here are my problems:

1. The cache works, because I see the shopping cart in the top bar update and when I change pages the top bar clearly comes out of the cache. However, the top bar still remains unchanged if I add an item to the cart. If I wait 60 seconds and reload, the cache version is expired and I get an updated and correct version.
2. The block cache does not seem to work if I switch to `<method>esi</method>`. In this case the cache never flushes.

The question:

How can I flush the ESI block cache on cart updates? And why does esi not work for me?

Comment: Have you gotten other blocks to work with ESI? When you set a block as ESI, do you see the HTML comments in the source code at the beginning and end of the block?

Comment: Yes, I see such comments for ESI blocks that are defined by the `turpentine_esi.xml`. Just not for my own!

Comment: If you turn on debugging in Turpentine - do you see anything mentioned about your block in the logs?